# Error when using SSL to connect to Apache FtpServer

Tags: java, ssl, apache-mina, apache-ftpserver

I'm trying to set up a simple test FTP server using Apache FtpServer, and I'm having trouble configuring to use SSL.

Following the [Apache FtpServer documentation](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html), here is what my code looks like so far:

```java
        FtpServerFactory ftpServerFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
        ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
        listenerFactory.setPort(990);
        listenerFactory.setServerAddress("example.com");

        SslConfigurationFactory sslConfigurationFactory = new SslConfigurationFactory();
        sslConfigurationFactory.setKeystoreFile(JKS);
        sslConfigurationFactory.setKeystorePassword(JKS_PASS);
        listenerFactory.setSslConfiguration(sslConfigurationFactory.createSslConfiguration());
        listenerFactory.setImplicitSsl(true);

        ftpServerFactory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());

        PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
        userManagerFactory.setFile(USERS_PATH.toFile());

        BaseUser test = new BaseUser();
        sample1.setName("test");
        sample1.setPassword("test");
        sample1.setHomeDirectory(HOME.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        test.setAuthorities(List.of(new WritePermission());

        UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
        try {
            userManager.save(test);
        }
        catch (FtpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ftpServerFactory.setUserManager(userManager);

        FtpServer server = ftpServerFactory.createServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        }
        catch (FtpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to connect to the FTPS server, I get this error from the server:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServer - FTP server started
[NioProcessor-1] WARN org.apache.mina.util.DefaultExceptionMonitor - Unexpected exception.
org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterLifeCycleException: onPreAdd(): sslFilter:SslFilter in (0x00000002: nio socket, server, /2.51.214.102:50475 => /142.93.208.41:990)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.register(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:465)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.addLast(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:234)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.buildFilterChain(DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.java:553)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:832)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:752)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:652)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported protocolTLS
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.namesOf(ProtocolVersion.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledProtocols(SSLEngineImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.init(SslHandler.java:184)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.onPreAdd(SslFilter.java:458)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.register(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:463)
    ... 9 more
```

From my client (FileZilla), I get this error:

```
Status:         Resolving address of itgsiatest.duss.app
Status:         Connecting to 142.93.208.41:990...
Status:         Connection established, initializing TLS...
Status:         Connection attempt failed with "ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer".
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What version of Java are you running? What versions of TLS does your server support?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm using Java 11. The supported TLS/SSL versions in my runtime (according to `SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()`) are TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, and SSLv2Hello.

Comment: You can set `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to get all the debugging in from the Java network stack - that should tell you what’s going on. Note that you **shouldn’t post the output** from that without careful review as is logs all the secret material.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've added this argument, but I don't see any new output. It seems to be truncated when the `[main] INFO org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServer - FTP server started` line comes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my bad, I put the argument under `Program arguments` instead of `VM options` in IntelliJ, which is why I wasn't able to get any output. Here's the output: https://0bin.net/paste/JVW1fNiI#-6YBq0EqKfBXysfmzd70wp+//AdhZcNAyCP9kMCAXtd

It's probably too verbose, so here's the output with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` instead of `-Djavax.net.debug=all`: https://0bin.net/paste/n8GGKc5f#gtEWEaLTl8sKnEYUfBP41UgEMyvqQY3X1jsS3XLG8Pn

Comment: I'm honestly quite surprised how problematic this turned out to be. I expected that it's possible to set up SSL on the only Java FTP library out there, especially since it's already documented.

I assumed that I must have messed something up in my set up, so I ran everything again in a new server, and I still have the exact same issues. Should I simply just give up SSL?

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you have managed to setup the FTP server [without encryption standalone](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/running_ftpserver_standalone.html).
2. I assume you have managed to set the FTP server [with encryption standalone](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/configuration_ssltls_support.html).
3. I assume you have managed to setup the FTP server [without encryption embedded](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html).
4. Now you are trying to combine **encryption and embedding**. As you correctly point out, this is also documented on step 3 and it seems your code directly follows the guide.

Yet the exception occurs when a client connects, and both client and server try to initialize the TLS handshake, which fails miserably on the server side. So something is still not right, and you need to search in the TLS area.

Have you checked your keystore content? Does it exist? Does it contain the correct certificate? Does it contain several certificates? What are their aliases? How come in your code you do not have to specify which certificate shall be used?
(the full documentation on the [keystore element](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/configuration_listeners.html) mentions a 'key alias', which could be set using [this method](https://github.com/apache/mina-ftpserver/blob/7b84f8648fb23312c6c796fbbc3910f50e35021b/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ftpserver/ssl/SslConfigurationFactory.java#L415).

The other thing to check is why in your log so many protocols should get ignored. What protocols remain to be used in the end?

Comment: Yeah, everything worked fine without SSL. In the `Embedding Apache FtpServer in 5 minutes` page (https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html), it shows how to create an embedded server with SSL, which is what I followed.